# .NET System.IO.PathTooLongException from Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2016, pathtoolongexception

Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 introduce solution for the traditional Long Path issue. The solution is straightforward to implement and detailed very good in the following [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/#comment-3445) post. Following the steps works successfully for a .NET console/desktop application. However, for some reason, when running the same code from a ASP.NET web application I still getting the same classic `System.IO.PathTooLongException` exception.

The code that throws exception:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(longPath);
```

As I mention, the code runs successfully on console application, but fails in ASP.NET website application. the website web.config includes the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false;Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths=false"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

and application manifest file as explained in the blog link above.

Any idea appreciated.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722086/uselegacypathhandling-is-not-loaded-properly-from-app-config-runtime-element Looks like there is a workaround in the linked question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UseLegacyPathHandling is not loaded properly from app.config runtime element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722086/uselegacypathhandling-is-not-loaded-properly-from-app-config-runtime-element)

Comment: Thank you @bradbury9, it's solve the problem on a POC. However, the production project based on .NET 4.5.1, which don't have the `AppContext` class to apply the solution. Any idea?

Comment: If the project uses a framework that does not have `AppContext`, most likely the .config `AppContextSwitchOVerrides` would not work 'cause the context does not exists. I dunno how to solve it in 4.5.1

Comment: @bradbury9 Thank you, I solved the issue, you can see the workaround. In my opinion, it's almost duplication, but the focus and the solution make it different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @bradbury9 that point me to similar issue, I confirmed that the application failed to load the switch long-path blockage settings in run-time. In addition, because the version of my application based on .NET 4.5.1, it's impossible to use the [AppContext class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) for manually set the desired switches programmatically.

Solution:

For ASP.NET web application, based on .NET 4.6.1 or below, make sure that .NET 4.6.2 is also installed on the machine that runs the application, and add the following attribute `targetFramework="4.6.2"` the the `httpRuntime` configuration.

Example:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" />
</system.web>
```

* Please notice that Windows that supports Long Path, such Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10, will have already .NET 4.6.2 installed

Comment: Glad to help ;-)