# PathTooLongException in new FileInfo

Tags: c#, .net, file, path

I have the following code:

```
    static long getFolderSize(string path)
    {
        string[] a = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        long b = 0;
        foreach (string name in a)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(name);
            b += fi.Length;
        }

        return b;
    }
```

In the environment where this code is running, there are paths that exceed the 260 character limit. Therefore the line

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfor(name);
```

throws a System.IO.PathTooLongException.

I've read a lot about this and according to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/ the problem should be solved in .NET 4.6.2. Therefore I've compiled the code in .NET 4.7 but still the same thing.

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087565/pathtoolongexception-in-c-sharp-code) thread I've tried to use [Delimon](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DelimonWin32IO-Library-V40-7ff6b16c)'s  Library but it throws a System.OverflowException in the line

```
string[] a = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Does anybody have a clue how tho solve this issue? (There is no way I change the file structure and using mapped drives is also no possibility).

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I added

```
<runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false;Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths=false"/>
</runtime>
```

To the app.config (note that it is a console application). Now there is a System.IO.FileNotFoundException thrown in the line

```
b += fi.Length;
```

**Edit2:**

This is how the app.config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=false;Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths=false"/>
        <runtime targetFramework="4.7"/>
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7"/>
        </runtime>
        <appSettings>
            <add key="SQLServer" value="Server2"/>
            <add key="database" value="FolderSizeMonitor"/>
            <add key="server" value="Server3"/>
        </appSettings>
        <startup>
            <dir ID="1" path="\\server20\d$\Data\BEG\Emergency\Emergency Management\Very Very Very Long pathVery Very Very Long path" DepthToLook="4">
            </dir>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET System.IO.PathTooLongException from Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476852/net-system-io-pathtoolongexception-from-web-application)

Comment: See edit. I am running Windows 10 (latest release) and .NET 4.7 installed.

Comment: In the linked question, the problem was that it needed to be enforced the framework version in the .config file. Maybe it helps you.

Comment: I do have the supportedRuntime tag in the app.config. Isn't that enough? If not, what is the equivalent for httpRuntime in Console Application?

Comment: should be enough, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5

Comment: still doesn't work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code did the trick:

```
    static long getFolderSize(string path)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        long b = 0;
        foreach(FileInfo fi in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            b += fi.Length;
        }

        return b;
    }
```