# Make MAF AddInProcess.exe "Long Path Aware"

Tags: c#, .net, windows, manifest, system.io.file

I'm trying to make my Addin's (using [MAF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sidharth/2009/05/03/working-with-the-managed-addin-framework-system-addin/)) AddInProcess.exe (created by the [AddInProcess class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.addin.hosting.addinprocess?view=netframework-4.7.2)) "long path aware" for Windows 10.

The difficulty stems from the fact that I don't *own* the AddInProcess.exe.  It is part of the .NET Framework, and lives in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\AddInProcess.exe`

Here's what I've done (based on following the guidance of *Jeremy Kuhne's Blog* entry [*.NET 4.6.2 and long paths on Windows 10*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/)):

- Set the `AppContext` switches `Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling` and `Switch.System.IO.BlockLongPaths` to `false`.  This made *some* .NET APIs start accepting long paths.  However, calls that under the hood called into *native* win32 still failed with `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` or other exceptions.
- The next thing I'm **supposed** to do, but can't is edit the application's manifest and add the settings below. However, there isn't a (correct) way for me to do this.  If I *could* do this it *would* work.  To prove that it would work, I did the following:

  - Created `AddInProcess.exe.manifest` with the below settings and dropped it into the directory right next to `AddInProcess.exe`.
  - This isn't enough for the manifest to be picked up because `AddInProcess.exe` has an embedded manifest (checked using [`sigcheck.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck)) and [embedded manifests take priority over external manifests](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2009/12/09/answers-to-several-application-manifest-mysteries-and-questions/).  I worked around this (for testing purposes) by [changing a registry setting that causes external manifests to take priority](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrisforster/2007/12/11/a-solution-and-workaround-to-the-change-in-manifest-preference-behaviour-in-windows-2003-sp1-and-windows-vista/).

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

While the above hack works, it's obviously not reasonable to do this on an end-user's machine and moreover, it would change the behavior for *all*  `AddInProcess.exe`, not just the ones I create.

**Question:** Is there a legitimate way to make a process you don't have control over (`AddInProcess.exe`) be `longPathAware`?

Is there a way to change this manifest setting at runtime?

**Notes**:

- I enabled Win32 Long Path Support in the Group Policy editor (see [.NET 4.6.2 and long paths on Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/))
- I had some difficulty getting the `AppContextSwitchOverrides` for `UseLegacyPathHandling` and `BlockLongPaths` to actually be respected.  I turned out to be [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40722086/uselegacypathhandling-is-not-loaded-properly-from-app-config-runtime-element) and I was able to workaround it.
- I *can* get the methods that don't work to start working by using *extended paths* (i.e. paths prepended with `\\?\` (since this causes path length checks to be skipped).  See [Path Normalization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/04/21/path-normalization/) blog entry.  However, this approach would be a much larger/riskier endeavor (trying to find all current code occurrences that would throw and modify the path and prevent future developers from adding new usages)

**Additional References**:

- [*More on new .NET path handling* - *Jeremy Kuhne's Blog*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/06/21/more-on-new-net-path-handling/)
- [Video: *Jeremy Kuhne - Long path support*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZppqEMegCAA)
- [Long Path Support .NET 4.6.2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/)
- [Setting machine wide AppContext switches via the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53193280/long-path-workaround-not-working-on-some-installs?rq=1)
- Kim Hamilton's series on Long Paths in .NET ([Part 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton/), [Part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/03/26/long-paths-in-net-part-2-of-3-long-path-workarounds-kim-hamilton/), [Part 3](http://%20https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2008/07/07/long-paths-in-net-part-3-of-3-redux-kim-hamilton/))

Comment: begin from 1709 version you can set [`IsLongPathAwareProcess`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntpebteb.h#L75) to 1 in *PEB* if such solution ok for you - `RtlGetCurrentPeb()->IsLongPathAwareProcess = 1;`

Comment: @RbMm I've tried out that approach, and my initial tests indicate it works!  Thank you.  The unfortunate thing about this approach is it is undocumented/unsupported.  I'm hoping for a supported approach.  But this is a good fallback, if there is nothing else.

Comment: i sure that just now not exist documented way do this. way with `IsLongPathAwareProcess` can be changed. most reliable way - use *\\\\?\\* win32 paths or nt functions

Comment: I am not sure if this could help or not as I have no experience in Addins, but it may worth to check. Please see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.addin.hosting.addinprocess?view=netframework-4.8). I wonder if the created external process (AddInProcess.exe) can take configuration from your code instead of its default.

Answer (score 0):

The undocumented approach suggested by **@RbMm** in the comments (setting the `PEB`'s `IsLongPathAwareProcess` bit to **1**) worked (at least on the version of Windows 10 I was on: 1903).  Since that approach is a native C/C++ approach, I just needed to translate that into something consumable by C#.

There are multiple approaches that can be used (C++/CLI, pinvoke).  Since I was just doing "proof of concept", I decided to just use pinvoke and be a bit lazy in the quality of the code.

Notes:

- This code does no version checking to see if it is running on a version of Windows 10 that supports `IsLongPathAwareProcess`.
- Limited error checking
- I only included the beginning part of the `PEB` structure, since that is all that is necessary to access the bit I want to modify.
- There's very likely a more concise way to set the `IsLongPathAwareProcess` bit than the approach I used (`Marshal.StructureToPtr`)
- Includes a test that works when the call to `SetIsLongPathAwareProcess` is executed and fails when it is not called
- Notice in the test code that I ***delete*** `C:\Test` (so that I can re-run the test multiple times without the directory already existing)

**Test Code:**

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetIsLongPathAwareProcess();

            string reallyLongDirectory = @"C:\Test\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            reallyLongDirectory = reallyLongDirectory + @"\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            reallyLongDirectory = reallyLongDirectory + @"\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            CreateDirTest(reallyLongDirectory);
            Directory.Delete(@"C:\Test", recursive: true);
        }

        private static void CreateDirTest(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Creating a directory that is {name.Length} characters long");

            // Test managed CreateDirectory
            Directory.CreateDirectory(name);

            // Test Native CreateDirectory.  Note this method will only create the "last part" of the directory (not the full path).
            // Also note that it fails if the directory already exists.
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya
            string nativeName = Path.Combine(name, "TestEnding");
            var r = Native.CreateDirectory(nativeName, null);
            if (!r)
            {
                int currentError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                Debug.Fail($"Native.CreateDirectory failed: {currentError}");
            }
        }


        // Adapted from https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ntdll.ntqueryinformationprocess
        private static void SetIsLongPathAwareProcess()
        {
            var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            IntPtr hProc = currentProcess.Handle;

            IntPtr pPbi = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Native.PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION)));
            IntPtr outLong = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(long));

            int status = Native.NtQueryInformationProcess(hProc, 0, pPbi, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Native.PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION)), outLong);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(outLong);

            //STATUS_SUCCESS = 0
            if (status == 0)
            {
                var pbi = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Native.PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION>(pPbi);
                var pPeb = pbi.PebBaseAddress;

                var peb = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Native.PEB_Beginning>(pPeb);

                var bitField1 = peb.BitField1;
                peb.BitField1 = bitField1 | Native.PEBBitField1.IsLongPathAwareProcess;
                Marshal.StructureToPtr<Native.PEB_Beginning>(peb, pPeb, false);
            }

            //Free allocated space
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pPbi);
        }

        static class Native
        {
            // http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION.html
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
            internal struct PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
            {
                public IntPtr ExitStatus;
                public IntPtr PebBaseAddress;
                public IntPtr AffinityMask;
                public IntPtr BasePriority;
                public UIntPtr UniqueProcessId;
                public IntPtr InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;

                public int Size
                {
                    get { return (int)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION)); }
                }
            }

            [Flags]
            internal enum PEBBitField1 : byte
            {
                None = 0,
                ImageUsesLargePages = 1 << 0,
                IsProtectedProcess = 1 << 1,
                IsImageDynamicallyRelocated = 1 << 2,
                SkipPatchingUser32Forwarders = 1 << 3,
                IsPackagedProcess = 1 << 4,
                IsAppContainer = 1 << 5,
                IsProtectedProcessLight = 1 << 6,
                IsLongPathAwareProcess = 1 << 7
            }

            // Note: this only contains the "beginning" of the PEB structure
            // but that is all we need for access to the IsLongPathAwareProcess bit
            // Used as a guide: https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntpebteb.h#L75
            // Related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-peb
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
            internal struct PEB_Beginning
            {
                Byte InheritedAddressSpace;
                Byte ReadImageFileExecOptions;
                Byte BeingDebugged;
                public PEBBitField1 BitField1;
            };

            // https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ntdll.ntqueryinformationprocess
            [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            internal static extern int NtQueryInformationProcess(IntPtr processHandle, int processInformationClass, IntPtr processInformation, uint processInformationLength, IntPtr returnLength);

            // The below is for test purposes only:
            // Include CreateDirectory for testing if the long path aware changes work or not.
            // Requires SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
            // http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateDirectory.html?diff=y
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping = false)]
            internal static extern bool CreateDirectory(String path, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes);


            // https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES.html
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            internal class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
            {
                internal int nLength = 0;
                // don't remove null, or this field will disappear in bcl.small
                internal unsafe byte* pSecurityDescriptor = null;
                internal int bInheritHandle = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

If you use this code in a Console App that is naturally `longPathAware`, you can still test that it works correctly, by manually setting `longPathAware` to `false` in the `app.manifest`:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">false</longPathAware>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>
```